# Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError when use krajee bootstrap file input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using krajee bootstrap file input for uploading multi files in Rails.
I got this Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError after I click upload button.
Anyone can help me. Thanks

```
class WorkFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :attachment,
    :styles => { :small => "150x150#"},
    :url => "/assets/work_files/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
    :path => ":rails_root/app/assets/images/work_files/:id/:style/:basename.:extension" 

  validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
  validates_attachment_size :attachment, :less_than => 1.megabytes
end
```

---

```
class WorkFilesController < ApplicationController

def upload
  @wf = WorkFile.new
  @wf.attachment = params[:pm_file_upload]
  @wf.save
end

end

Started POST "/work_files/upload" for 192.168.0.5 at 2016-02-02 21:51:17 +0000
Processing by WorkFilesController#upload as JSON
  Parameters: {"pm_file_upload"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x55acb48 @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/bC/bCJs3dCDGoa9n-zhECDRnU+++TI/-Tmp-/RackMultipart20160202-44332-wpd4ik>, @original_filename="hello world.pdf", @content_type="application/pdf", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"pm_file_upload[]\"; filename=\"hello world.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n">], "file_id"=>"0"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms

Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError (No handler found for [#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x55acb48 @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/bC/bCJs3dCDGoa9n-zhECDRnU+++TI/-Tmp-/RackMultipart20160202-44332-wpd4ik>, @original_filename="hellow world.pdf", @content_type="application/pdf", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"pm_file_upload[]\"; filename=\"hello world.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n">]):
  app/controllers/work_files_controller.rb:5:in `upload'
```

Comment: In your form, are you passing it as a multi-part-form?

Answer (score 0):

change `@wf.attachment = params[:pm_file_upload]` 
to `@wf.attachment = params[:pm_file_upload][0]`